# Probability with 3 variables

Tags: python

I am working with balls being pulled from a box. I have 3 arguments and i am supposed to return 1 value: a floating-point number, the probability that at least one ball from the "number" drawn from the box is the specified color

The instructions: Write a function which:

is named select_chances
takes 3 arguments: a list of colors of balls in an urn (same as input to Part A), an integer number (number of balls to draw out of the urn), and a string containing a single color
returns 1 value: a floating-point number, the probability that at least one ball from the "number" drawn from the urn is the specified color
Remember, you compute probability exactly as before--the number of events of interest (selecting a certain number of balls with at least one of a certain color) divided by the total number of possible events (all possible draws)--only this time you'll need to account for combinations of multiple balls.

For example, if I give you an urn list of ["blue", "green", "red"], the number 2, and the query color "blue", then you would return 2/3, or 0.66666 (There are three possible combinations of groupings of 2 balls: blue-green, blue-red, and green-red. Two of these three combinations contain the query color blue).

I have inputted a defined code with the variables and am struggling on how to do an if and elif statement with the 3 arguments or if that is even the protocol - the instructor did not post a good lecture on inputting probability into python.

```py
from itertools import combinations as c

def select_chances(colors, two, blue): 
    if i in colors is blue:
           colors = two
    else:
            colors = other 
    print(colors)

return select_chances
```

Any recommended resources as well as help would be very much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Hi, can your format your code? It's really necessary with Python because indentation matters. Or else we don't know what it means. Also, can you elaborate a bit about the expected behavior? I'm not sure I understand what the inputs are supposed to be.

Comment: You should first format the code in the question correctly (including indentation) and explain what the parameters actually mean. It seems the balls are colored?

Comment: I think the question needs further editing to clarify what probability is being calculated, and what the issue with the code is. It looks like there are some variables here (like `other`) which may be undefined, or they may be defined in another part of the code we can't see.

Comment: Hello all, i uploaded the literal instructions for what we need to do

Comment: The phrase "you compute probability exactly as before" sounds like you have had at least one previous exercise in computing probabilities. Your code also looks like you need to review quite a lot of fundamentals about Python, including how a function that returns one floating-point value is not the same as a function that prints a list of strings.

Comment: To clarify the example: if you execute `print(select_chances(["blue","green","red"], 2, "blue"))`, your program should print 0.66666 (or something close), nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the problem statement is a little unclear to me. We have a list `colors` which indicates the colors of balls. Do we have infinitely many (or a lots of compared to how many we draw) balls of each color, or just one? Assuming infinitely many means you can draw the same color over and over.

Your function has bad argument names. This is an example case that you mentioned above. (and by the way, two should be 2, and blue should be 'blue')

```py
def select_chances(colors, two, blue):
```

It should be something like:

```py
def select_chances(colors, n, target):
```

Also, adding docstring to your function is useful, because when you show your code to someone else, or years later you want to understand what does it do you can immediately see. So let's do that:

```py
def select_chances(colors, n, target): 
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    colors: list
    contains all balls' color as strings which we chose from.
    (note that repeated items are treated as unique)

    n: int
    number of draws

    target: string
    the target color we are interested in

    Returns
    -------
    prob: float
    probability of drawing at least one of the specified color
    '''
```

Let's start with an easy case: if you give a color which is not in the urn, the probability is zero.

```py
if target not in colors:
    return 0
```

Next, we need all of the unique combinations of the given colors. This can be achieved with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```py
all_unique_outcomes = list(combinations(colors, n))
```

Counting the good cases:

```py
counter = 0
for element in all_unique_outcomes:
    if target in element:
        counter += 1
```

The classical probability is defined as events of interest divided by all cases.

```py
prob = counter/len(all_unique_outcomes)
```

Putting it all together:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def select_colors(colors, n, target):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------

    colors: list
    contains all balls' color as strings which we chose from.
    (note that repeated items are treated as unique)

    n: int
    number of draws

    target: string
    the target color we are interested in

    Returns
    -------
    prob: float
    probability of drawing at least one of the specified color
    '''
    if target not in colors:
        return 0
    all_unique_outcomes = list(combinations(colors, n))
    counter = 0
    for element in all_unique_outcomes:
        if target in element:
            counter += 1
    prob = counter/len(all_unique_outcomes)
    return prob

# example usage

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow']

print(select_colors(colors, 2, 'red'))
```

It seems you need to check the basics of functions, because what you posted there is messy. For example:

- variable other is not defined
- you try to return your function itself without arguments at wrong identation level